# Error: View does not exist in the registry

Tags: javascript, macos, boot

I'm trying to load one of my company website in the browser which tends to give me this error:

```
boot.js.uncompressed.js:10048 Error: View does not exist in the registry: homepage
```

I get this error across all browsers. I'm using macOS.
Can anyone help here?